# How to create unique subpage for each row in php and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have one table with 4 columns (id, name, surname, url). I want to create unique subpage for each row. (example.com/id?=444). So if I visit example.com?id=444 I will see data from row which has id 444.

Right now I have form where you add data into database:

```
> <form action="motogp.php" method="POST"> <input type="text"
> name="name" placeholder="Ime"> <input type="text" name="surname"
> placeholder="Priimek"> <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="URL
> do slike"> <button type="reset" class="ui button">Počisti</button>
> <button type="submit" class="ui positive button">Pošlji</button>
> </form>
```

Now it gives me just example.com/motogp.php not example.com/?id=444.

Results page code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO person (name, surname, url)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[sruname]','$_POST[url]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<h2>VIDEO: " . $row['name'] . . $row['surname'] . " z drugo zaporedno zmago zmanjšal zaostanek za Marquezom</h2>";
  echo "<img src='images/avoter.png'>";
  echo "<img src='" .  $row['url'] ."'>";

}
```

Comment: if you use  mysql_  functions in your code, you are now hackable via SQL Injection, DO NOT USE THESE FUNCTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is

```
 SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

That will retrieve the last row (highest-id row) from your table. If more than one user is using the system, that won't always be the row you want.

You probably want

```
 SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

This will pull out the data for the row you just inserted.

On the page where your URL includes ?id=444 you'll want

```
 SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = ?
```

and bind the value of the ID in the URL to the SQL parameter, `$_REQUEST['id']`.

Comment: Where should I use " SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = ?" and where $_REQUEST['id']? Sorry, I don't understand.